# Bluetooth audio adapter confusion - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

There are two places where I live, and in each I have a stereo system that I connect to my (Windows 10 Home) laptop with a Bluetooth audio adapter. The two adapters are both made by Logitech but are different models. Having used the bluetooth adapter successfully at one place, when I go to the other place, the other adapter will not connect, and I have to remove the device, and add it again. This is a real pain. Also, when I delete the device, then reinstall, I get a "Device not migrated" event in the device properties:

```
Device BTHENUM\Dev_C0288D3CB4E5\7&1fc36906&0&BluetoothDevice_C0288D3CB4E5 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.
Last Device Instance Id: BTH\MS_BTHL2CAP\6&9ea95fe&0&2
Class Guid: {E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFFFFFFF102
Present: true
Status: 0xC0000719
```

Here is the newer version of the adapter: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-Bluetooth-Receiver-Audio-Adapter/dp/B00IJYG4FY, and here is the older version: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0057BAB60/. I have one of each, one in one location, and one in the other, plugged into the hifi and the mains electricity via an AC adapter.

It's as if Windows thinks the two devices are the same and is using whatever drivers it installed for the other one, which then don't work as they are very different models, though of the same brand and with the same basic name. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I am wondered why you need 2 adapters. If this is Bluetooth audio then any adapter can work with any Bluetooth Audio device. About your question: do you have both adapters plugged in or changed them each tome you change your location?

Comment: @MikePetrichenko The adapters are plugged into the hifi at each location and into the mains electricity via an AC adapter. I don't want to carry the bluetooth audio adapter and power supply between each location and plug it in each time.

Comment: I see. The one of possible problem then is pairing. The devices looks identical for Windows and it can not establish connection because of previous pairing. It shard to say what exactly goes wrong without analizing communication dump but all looks like pairing issue. Solution: 2 hardware profiles or software that will repair your devices automatically.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Yes, it is as if some layer of Windows has seen "Logitech BT Adapter" (which is what each one is listed at in Bluetooth settings), then another layer has installed the drivers for *that particular version* of the hardware. Then I go to the other place, it sees "Logitech BT Adapter", tries to use the same drivers, but it doesn't work because it is a different version of the hardware and the drivers are incompatible.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko The easy solution (though not cost-effective) would be buy another Bluetooth adapter that is either identical to the newer one so the same drivers work for both, or a different brand that Windows can differentiate between. I am interested to know, though, how the Windows Bluetooth stack identifies devices and decides which drivers to install. I would like to save to a text file the driver details that are listed in the adapter properties and compare them between the drivers installed for each adapter, but I can't find a way to do this. Maybe that should be another question.

Comment: It works a bit different. Each Bluetooth adapter installed as "only one device" and has own list of paired devices. Even you may see the device in Windows Devices list the device is not present in the system because it Device Object has not been created when Windows loads drivers for Bluetooth adapter. You can see it in the system Registry.

Comment: Probably buy new absolutely identical Bluetooth adapter may solve the problem but the adapter must be absolutely identical (including VID, PID and revision).