# How to save driver details to a text file - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I am trying to diagnose a problem where Windows is mistaking two different Bluetooth audio devices for the same device (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1340235/bluetooth-audio-adapter-confusion-windows-10)). As part of my investigations, I would like to save the details of the driver installed for each device to a text file (i.e., the information on Device Manager -> Bluetooth -> Logitech BT Adapter -> Properties -> Details). Is there a program which can give me quick access to this information rather than having to copy each detail manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using software, there are several free diagnostic tools out there. Once I used a tool, that could export all the driver details into a text file. From all or just from selected drivers...  "driver manager s.th." - I think. I'll try to look for it and let you know...

**Update:**
I found a portable version of a similar software for Windows 7 (won't work with Windows 8) "SIW (System Information for Windows) Portable": https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/siw_portable

You can see an overview of all details for any device that is in the device manager. There is a copy to clipboard function (the export function is not for free) that lets you copy the information from all devices to the clipboard. Then you just have to select the text block for your specific device manually.

**Update:**
For Windows 8 there is an Command line Tool "DevCon - ... that displays detailed information about devices on computers running Windows": https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon

Comment: I installed SIW and got 
"SIW Home Edition is not supported on Windows 8 (Windows Version 6.2)
Only SIW Pro works on Windows 8
The program will now close"

Comment: Ah, I think DevCon might be able to help... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

Comment: @drkvogel ok, yeah, you didn't specify the windows version, so I did not check. Let us know if it did/didn't work. I updated my answer and included your comment.